# How to replace a string without knowing its exact value?

Tags: php

I'm very new to PHP, and want to know how to `str_replace()` if I do not know its exact value.

IE:
"RESPONSE 401", how would I replace that to be nothing, if I did not know that 401 was is it, but I did always know it was a 3 digit value?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `preg_replace` instead:

```
$string = 'RESPONSE 401';
$pattern = '/(RESPONSE) (\d{3})/';
$replacement = '$1';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

`preg_replace` uses regex, which allows you to not be "specific" when searching. It's unclear if you want the entire match to be replaced with nothing. If that's the case then just remove `$1` from the replacement and it will replace the entire string to be blank.

↳ http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: I think the string is just `RESPONSE 401`